# passing value of database handler object in to onClickListener

Tags: android

I need help on passing value of database helper object to onCilckListener..

The database helper works fine if it's outside the listener.. But the application stops due to an exception when it is used inside the listener.. Please help me..

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        DatabaseHandler dbpin = new DatabaseHandler(this);


        // Inserting Pin
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting Pin ..");
        dbpin.addPin(new Pin("1111"));
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading pin at id=0..");

        Pin cn1 = dbpin.getPin(0);
        String log1 = cn1.getPin() ;
          Log.d("Name: ", log1);     //this works.. i want the value of log1 inside OnClickListener of imageButton1

        ImageButton next2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        next2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

            EditText pinget = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);


                 Log.v("EditText", pinget.getText().toString());



             //pin validator

          //value of log1 should be retrieved here to compare it in the if condition

                      if (pinget.getText().toString().equals("0000")) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), home.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
                }
                 else {
                     Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main1.class);
                     startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
                 }

            }                

        });      
    }      
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change

```
String log1 = cn1.getPin() ;
```

to

```
final String log1 = cn1.getPin();
```

you can access `log1` inside the onClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
String log1 = cn1.getPin();
```

to this

```
final String log1 = cn1.getPin();
```